# MongoDB C# Driver: flatten object

Tags: c#, mongodb

Imagine I have a class structure like this

```
class Aggregate
{
    string Id {get;set;}
    Parameters Parameters {get;set;}
}

class Parameters
{
    List<string> Values {get;set;}
    // logic based on Values
}
```

Now  I want mongo to store it like this

```
{
    "_id": "...",
    "parameters": ["param A", "param B"]
}
```

How do I configure it using `BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap`?

Comment: P.S. by default it produces structure like this
`{
    "_id": "...",
    "parameters": {
        "values": [...]
    }
}`

Comment: Do you want your private members `Id`, `Parameters` and `Values` to be serialized in camel case? Or is the members being private just an oversight?

Answer (score 0):

I'm ignoring the fact that the members of your class are private at the moment, as that would mean you couldn't read anything from the class. So let's just make them public

```cs
    class Aggregate
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public Parameters Parameters { get; set; }
    }

    class Parameters
    {
        public List<string> Values { get; set; }
    }
```

So now we'll need a custom serializer to deal with flattering the object and then also reading back the flattened document.

Below is just a noddy example that delegate serializing `Parameters` to the `BsonArraySerializer`.

```
public class ParametersSerializer : IBsonSerializer
{
    private readonly BsonArraySerializer _bsonArraySerializer;

    public ParametersSerializer()
    {
        _bsonArraySerializer = new BsonArraySerializer();
    }
    public object Deserialize(BsonDeserializationContext context, BsonDeserializationArgs args)
    {
        var bsonArray = _bsonArraySerializer.Deserialize(context, args);

        var netList = BsonTypeMapper.MapToDotNetValue(bsonArray, new BsonTypeMapperOptions()
        {
            MapBsonArrayTo = typeof(List<string>)
        }) as List<string>;
        return new Parameters
        {
            Values = netList 
        };
    }

    public void Serialize(BsonSerializationContext context, BsonSerializationArgs args, object value)
    {
        var typed = (Parameters) value;
        var bsonArray = new BsonArray(typed.Values);

        _bsonArraySerializer.Serialize(context, args, bsonArray);
    }

    public Type ValueType { get; } = typeof(Parameters);
}
```

Now we've got this we can just add an attribute to our class to tell Mongo driver to use it.

```cs
class Aggregate
{
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [BsonSerializer(typeof(ParametersSerializer))]
    public Parameters Parameters { get; set; }
}
```

Now when we write and read documents to mongo:

```cs
var pack = new ConventionPack();
pack.Add(new CamelCaseElementNameConvention());

ConventionRegistry.Register(
    "My Custom Conventions",
    pack,
    t => t == typeof(Aggregate) || t == typeof(Parameters));

var client = new MongoClient();
var database = client.GetDatabase("test");
var collection = database.GetCollection<Aggregate>("test");
await database.DropCollectionAsync(collection.CollectionNamespace.CollectionName);

await collection.InsertOneAsync(new Aggregate{Id = "...", Parameters = new Parameters{Values = {"1", "2"}}});
var all = await (await collection.FindAsync(Builders<Aggregate>.Filter.Empty)).ToListAsync();
```

we'll get the following save in MongoDB collection:

```js
> db.test.find()
{ "_id" : "...", "parameters" : [ "1", "2" ] }
```

Also notice we're using a custom convention of camel case to deal with creating camel case properties too.